# Resolving dual boot problems

Tags: multi-boot, grub, bcd

I cannot successfully boot Windows through GRUB (BSOD), and cannot booth Linux through the Windows bootloader. My primary goal is to boot both Linux and Windows using a single bootloader, preferably GRUB, but other options are acceptable.

**The setup**

Desktop PC with two M2 NVME SSDs. One is supposed to be fully for Linux and one fully for Windows.

- I have first installed Linux (Pop OS 20.04) on one drive.
- I have later installed Windows 10, choosing another drive.
- It wouldn't boot properly.
- I applied various fixes and reached a point where I have a working GRUB and can use both OSes.

**The problem**

When I try to boot Windows from GRUB it BSODs with 0xc000000e.
Windows boots normally if I choose "Windows boot manager" entry as "what to boot" in BIOS.

**What fixes did I try**

- I've discovered that Windows Boot Manager originally got installed on my "Linux drive" boot partition.
- I've used Linux "dd" terminal command to copy the boot partition from Linux drive to Windows drive, to be more sure that using various BCD repair commands won't mess up my GRUB.
- I've then deleted the Windows folder from EFI from Linux drive boot partition.

Unfortunately the fixes broke various Windows boot repair commands, as it seems something's left of BCD on the Linux drive and Windows can't distinguish between BCDs on two drives.

**Possible direction for a solution**
One of the things I'd like to do is destroy any remnants of BCD on my Linux drive (Can I nuke boot partition and then recreate it while still being logged into Linux, without messing aroung with recovery drives?)

For troubleshooting, I wanted to disable the Linux drive and then reinstall Windows, but I haven't found a way to disable the drives from BIOS (Motherboard is [ASUS ROG Maximus XI Hero](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/ROG_MAXIMUS_XI_HERO_WIFI/E14964_ROG_MAXIMUS_XI_HERO_WI-FI_BIOS_EM_WEB.pdf?_ga=2.230782550.857060770.1591363965-661415243.1591141788)).

**Restrictions**

I can't nuke my Linux - I need it for work.
I can't physically remove any of the SSDs - the screws on my motherboard were stripped.

**Additional info**

Everything's "modern" - drives use GPT partitioning, and the boot partitions are EFI. SecureBoot is off in BIOS.

I tried obvious options like grub-update and Boot Repair tool

Comment: Doesn't DIMM mean RAM?

Comment: Usually yes, but Asus is being whacky: https://www.techpowerup.com/229448/asus-dimm-2-is-an-m-2-riser-card

Comment: I'll try it, but I'm not sure it applies to my motherboard. You've missed the model a bit, this is the one: https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/ROG_MAXIMUS_XI_HERO_WIFI/E14964_ROG_MAXIMUS_XI_HERO_WI-FI_BIOS_EM_WEB.pdf
The only times it mentions DIMM looks really RAM-related. There are 4 RAM slots on the motherboard, and it allows you to disable Channel A slot 1 or 2 and Channel B slot 1 or 2

Comment: Thanks for correcting. Your model doesn't seem to call it DIMM. To recap: I would indeed try to disable the Linux drive while installing Windows. Can you try, in the same menu Advanced->Onboard Devices configuration-> Hyper M.2 X16: [Disable]. Then it should disable one of the 2 nvme drives. Let's hope it disables the right one. If this disables the wrong one, maybe try to set M.2_1 Configuration to [SATA mode]. This might make the other drive undetectable.

Comment: While Hyper M.2 is about extension slots akin to this one: https://www.amazon.ca/M-2-X16-Expansion-V2-Supports/dp/B07NQBQB6Z
I indeed managed to disable the Linux drive by setting M.2_1 Configuration option to "SATA mode". I've since reinstalled Windows, let's see if it helps

Comment: Please visit this page (one of Stack Exchange's many sites), AskUbuntu "Is it possible to boot Ubuntu using the Windows bootloader?" https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader  "EasyBCD is 100% UEFI-ready. In UEFI mode, much of EasyBCD’s functionality will be disabled for the safety of your PC." https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/uefi/